# Orthogonal columns of a nonsquare matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, svd, orthogonal-matrices

Consider a SVD of a $3 \times 2$ matrix $A$, why the product of a $2 \times 2$ $S$ orthogonal matrix  $AS$ has orthogonal columns while the product of a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix $SA$ won't?

I don't know how to prove that this is true.